# Add/Remove active class from dynamically built list of buttons for sidebar

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building out the bootstrap sidebar for my react project which has lists of dynamically generated buttons. On-click I want to add the `active` class to the button that is clicked and clear it from any other buttons (if there's one selected).

I read about the [classNames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) library and haven't been able to make that work. Here's an example of one of the groups of buttons:

classnames:

```
var btnClass = classnames({
      btn: true,
      'btn-link': true,
      'nav-link': true,
      'active': // not sure what to use here
    });
```

button example

```
<ul class="nav flex-column">
   { checkingAccounts.map((account) => {
       return (
         <li className="nav-item">
           <button eventKey={account.id} type="button" className={btnClass} onClick={this.handleAccountSelect} value={account.id}>
             { account.account_name }
           </button>
         </li>
       )
   })}
</ul>
```

and my state and handler

```
this.state = {
      data: [],
      checkingAccounts: [],
      savingsAccounts: [],
      creditCardAccounts: [],
      selectedAccount: null,
    }
  }

  handleAccountSelect = (event) => {
    console.log(event)
    this.props.handleAccountSelect(event.target.value)
    this.setState({
      selectedAccount: event.target.value
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place that `btnClass` inside the loop so it changes per button, the you can compare with the selected item in the state.

```
<ul class="nav flex-column">
   {checkingAccounts.map((account) => {
      var btnClass = classnames({
        btn: true,
        'btn-link': true,
        'nav-link': true,
        'active': state.selectedAccount === account.id // whatever value is .value
      });

       return (
         <li className="nav-item">
           <button eventKey={account.id} type="button" className={btnClass} onClick={this.handleAccountSelect} value={account.id}>
             { account.account_name }
           </button>
         </li>
       )
   })}
</ul>
```